# Custom post types archive redirect

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, htaccess, slug

I had a custom post type with slug as (**sometext**) which I changed to (**someothertext**)
And it works great

So for example :

my posts with urls like

```
http://localhost/sometext/innerposts
```

gets redirected to

```
http://localhost/someothertext/innerposts
```

but not my archive page

basically I would like to redirect

```
http://localhost/sometext/ to
http://localhost/someothertext/
```

in my .htaccess file 
I tried adding a string to make it work

```
RewriteRule ^/sometext$ ^/someothertext/$ [R=301,L]
```

but it fails.

I'm very poor with .htaccess rewrites. I'll really appreciate if someone helps me out with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The link to the archive page is saved into WordPress rewrite rules. These rules are used to locate several locations on the front end of your WordPress system. When you change the `slug` of a Custom Post Type, the normal pages will redirect directly to the new location, but the archive page won't, this because the rewrite rules aren't regenerated.

To solve this, go to **Settings** -> **Permalinks** and save your permalink structure again, reload your page and the archive page will load correctly.

The rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` won't be needed.

Also, **never** put any rewrite rules in your `.htaccess` except the ones WordPress writes into it.
If you want to add some rules, do this by using the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API).

Comment: hi Mike, thanks for your reply. I'm afraid it does not work. As i said in my question urls to my posts are getting redirected successfully but not for archive pages.  (I already flushed rewrite rules by visiting Settings -> Permalinks)

Comment: Do you have the argument `has_archive` in the `register_post_type` function on `true`, or on `sometext`? It could it be that you'll have the archive manual directed to `sometext`?

Comment: yes mike 'has_archive' is set to true, and not set as sometext. 

I also tried changin 'has_archive' => 'someothertext' but still it returns 404

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned. Never put any rewrite rules in your .htaccess, use [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) instead. To reach your goal, use following code in your functions.php or site-specific plugin:

```
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_rules' );
function my_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'sometext/(.+?)/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?someothertext='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),     
        'sometext/(.+?)/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?someothertext='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ). '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 2 ),               
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```